# Find the angle between the following vector

Tags: linear-algebra

- Find the angle between the following vectors: $X=(1,-3,4)$ and $Y=(4,2,1)$.

My solution is: $X \cdot Y=\| X\|\| Y\|\cos\theta$. Hence, we get $\cos\theta=2/\sqrt {546}$.

**Can you check my answer/method?**

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, right. It is a typo

Comment: @Kahler Sorry, I wasn't entirely sure. But if so your answer is correct.

Comment: Hence, $\theta=arcos (2/\sqrt {546})$

Comment: @Kahler  Please, if you are ok you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems correct

$$X \cdot Y =4-6+4=2$$

$$\|X\|=\sqrt{26}$$

$$\|Y\|=\sqrt{21}$$

$$\|X\|\|Y\|=\sqrt{546}$$

but

$$\cos \theta=\frac{2}{\sqrt{546}}\implies\theta=\arccos \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{546}}\right)$$

Comment: Hence, $\theta=arcos (2/\sqrt {546})$

Comment: @Kahler yes of course!

Comment: It is answer for my question,right?

Comment: @Kahler Yes. It is.

Comment: @Kahler Yes it is absolutely correct. $\arccos $ returns the angle (in general $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$) between the two vectors.

Comment: I changed $||X||||Y||$ to $\|X\|\|Y\|.$ That is standard usage.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks now it looks very good!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. Note that we have $$\cos \theta=\frac{2}{\sqrt{546}}$$
Not $$\theta=\frac{2}{\sqrt{546}}$$
But aside from that, your answer sems fine. Just fix this up.

Comment: You are right,.

Comment: @Kahler Yeah, I realize your mistake was just a typo. Anyway it's right. (Also, I don't like correcting grammar but it's "You are right" not "Your are right."...)

Comment: Hence, $\theta=arcos (2/\sqrt {546})$

Comment: @Kahler Your conclusion is correct. But please write the arccosine function as `$\arccos$` not `$arcos$`.

Comment: Okey, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $\|\vec{X}\| = \sqrt{26}, \|\vec{Y}\| = \sqrt{21}$ and
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{X} \cdot \vec{Y}}{\|\vec{X}\|\|\vec{Y}\|} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{546}}
$$

Comment: $|Y| = \sqrt{21}$

Comment: @Y.Forman fixed it thanks

Comment: Hence, $\theta=arcos (2/\sqrt {546})$

Comment: @Kahler : Could you write $\arccos(\cdot)$ instead of $arccos(\cot)$? The backslash not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $a\arccos b,$ where otherwise you'd see $a\text{arccos} b$ or $a arccos b$.

Comment: Okey, thanks...

Comment: @MichaelHardy just typo, fixed thanks